# Change the default opening file github pages

Tags: github, github-pages

So i create a simple test repository https://github.com/mugas/imdb/.
The branch is gh-pages and I have an index.html file but it still opens the readme.md file instead. How can I change it to open the index.html?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Github Pages does not effect your normal repository page. It effects your github.io page.

You'll want to read the [Github Help for Pages Basics](https://help.github.com/categories/github-pages-basics/) and the instructions for [Configuring Github Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/).